# Android: How can I get the layout of a fragment instance by way of tag?

Tags: java, android

Right now I"m inside a fragment, and I'm adding another fragment to the fragment I currently occupy. I'm doing it like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2, fragString);
```

But the fragment I'm nested in is itself added multiple times, so I could be in any one(there are tags on those, if that helps). What I figured would happen is my new frag, frag2, would get added to my current parent fragment at R.id.templateFragmentLayout. But what is happening is when my parent frag has multiple instances, frag2 only ever gets added to the original R.id.templateFragmentLayout, not to any of the corresponding new instances.

So what I"m wondering is, can I somehow specify which fragment to add to? Something like this

```
fragmentTransaction.add((R.id.templateFragmentLayout of my current fragment), frag2, fragString);
```

or

```
fragmentTransaction.add((R.id.templateFragmentLayout of tagged fragment "x"), frag2, fragString);
```

This is my first question on here, so please let me know if there's anything I should add, I just didn't want to clutter it up with a super long post if there's something simple I"m missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so in case anyone comes across this with the same issue, I figured it out. In my child fragment, I just had to call getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().

Answer (score 0):

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.templateFragmentLayout, frag2, fragString);

Fragment fragment_byTag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragString");

Comment: Are you saying to add the second line Fragment fragment_byTag... after that first line? I really don't understand what you're saying. That throws an error "cannot resolve method."